# How to make this ajax request work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

After browsing through the web, and looking at some W3schools example (albeit it was in .asp) I decided to write the following function in my JS file:

```
function meaning(){

    var sel = $("#allnames");
    var name = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;

    $.post("babynames.php",
    {
       type: "meaning",
       name: name
    },
    function (data) {
        document.getElementById("meaning").innerHTML = data;
    });
}
```

It references a .php file, which used to be .html, that contains a selector which is populated by including a populateDropDown function from our babynames.php. I am wondering how to link the above JS function, to this php function:

```
function populateMeaning() {
    $meanings = fopen("meanings.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file");

    $option = $_POST['name'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];

    while(!feof($meanings)) {
        $selectOption = strtoupper($option);
        $line = fgets($meanings);

        if(strpos($line,$selectOption ) !== false) {
            $meaning = substr($line, strpos(0, ' '), strlen($line));
            ob_start();
            print $meaning;
            ob_end_flush();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I was using the following two websites. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp and also http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/node/view/32 since w3schools used .asp code instead of php.

So the end result would be that the currently empty div "meaning" be populated by the meaning result we get after we parse through a file. However, if I manually include the above populate function inside of my index.php using  it says undefined index, and it starts with the POST method as the issue. If I do not include said function then I am quite positive it is never executed.

Thus, to conclude, how to get the desired result (that is div being set to the parsed meaning), and where did I go wrong in translating that W3schools example into my code?

Comment: I doubt jQuery has a type of "meaning" - `type: "meaning"`.

Comment: probably so, however, based on my limited understanding isn't it like passing parameters to the php file? So it would be like babynames.php?type=meaning&name=<w.e name is set to>? Currently I just want to make the name aspect of it work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the second argument to [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) is data, not $.ajax config

Comment: @SomeStudent does your `populateMeaning()` get called in the PHP file? If you change the `$_POST` vars to `$_GET` vars you can quickly test to see the output by going to `yourscript.php?name=foo&type=meaning`

Answer (score 0):

Your php function will not able to catch `POST` request
first get your post parameters

```
$option = $_POST['name'];
 $type = $_POST['type'];
```

pass those variables to php function

```
function populateMeaning($option,$type) {
    $meanings = fopen("meanings.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file");

    while(!feof($meanings)) {
        $selectOption = strtoupper($option);
        $line = fgets($meanings);

        if(strpos($line,$selectOption ) !== false) {
            $meaning = substr($line, strpos(0, ' '), strlen($line));
            ob_start();
            print $meaning;
            ob_end_flush();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now it will work.
your jquery code is correct no need to change

Then call php function

```
populateMeaning($option,$type);
```

Comment: Will try that, now when you say call, is it in the index.php?

Comment: No in babynames.php

Comment: still no go. That portion of the div remains empty.

Comment: have you checked in console what are you getting in response?

Comment: console mentions only not being able to find CSS, which is fine as i do not have it yet. The output on the screen once I manually call on that populate function within my names.php (i.e the index) is Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\CSCI4300\p7-oophp\babynames.php on line 20

Comment: which is the location where we say _POST['name']

Comment: anywhere in babyname.php before calling populateMeaning($option,$type);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127463/discussion-between-rajesh-patel-and-somestudent).

Answer (score 0):

In babynames.php you only have to call

```
populateMeaning();
```

After you defined the function.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution using the following:

I made another php file whose sole function is to call the php function I require as follows:

```
require_once 'babynames.php';

if(isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $option = $_GET['name'];

    populateMeaning($option, NULL);
}
```

In the babynames.php file, the corresponding function echos the meaning.

The JS then looks like this:

```
function meaning(){
    // var sel = $("#allnames");
    // var name = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;

    nested = document.getElementById("allnames");
    nested = nested.options[nested.selectedIndex].value;

    $.get("populateMeaningActual.php",
    {
       type: "meaning",
       name: nested
    },
    function (data) {
        //alert("Data loaded " + data);
        document.getElementById("meaning").innerHTML = data;
    });
}
```

Which hasn't really changed at all from the original. I believe the missing piece was the `isset`.